# NodeJS and Express: On page load, nothing displays, then on refresh everything pulls through. JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Been trying to figure this out for a while, but having some trouble.

I am working on a project that on page load, loads a remote JSON file into memory, parses it, and then displays the results to the page (pug).

Everything works fine, apart from when the page is first loaded, I get the message "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" displayed on the page. Then when I refresh, the page works as expected.

I have a function called **requestjson**, that requests the json file and stores it in a variable (for testing)

I have a prototype **randomizer.fetch** that parses the JSON file, and saves into an object.

With callbacks I've tried to stagger the functions so they only start when the other has finished etc, but it seems like the page is rendering before they have done their job. I can see them all work as expected using console.log in the background.

I've tried creating middleware, and get the same issue.

Heres some code

```
function handler(req, res, next) {

randomizer.empty();

  //loads the req object with the properties in from the .gets
  var routerObj = req.routerObj;

  requestjson(randomizer.fetch,  routerObj.jsonurl);

  //renders the pug file 'routerObj.destination' and passes variables into it.
  return res.render(routerObj.destination, {"urlImg": randomizer.urlImg, "randomValue": randomizer.randomValue, "vidURL" : randomizer.vidURL, "objTitle" :
  randomizer.objTitle, "objLink" : randomizer.objLink, "objEmbed" : randomizer.objEmbed});

}

router.get('/pics', (req, res, next) => {
    req.routerObj = {
          destination: 'pics',
          jsonurl: 'https://www.foobar.com',
          saveparam: ''
      };
       next();
}, handler );
```

And here is the function

```
function requestjson(callback, json) {

  request.get(json, function (err, res, data) {

    if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now

    if (data) {

        //data = data.trim();      Dont think needed

        storage = JSON.parse(data);

    }

  })

callback(json);

}
```

Any ideas? All help appreciated!

## **Solved**

Finally fixed the problem, I changed my requestjson call to

```
requestjson(randomizer.fetch, routerObj.jsonurl, function() {

res.render method....

}
```

and added an extra callback2(res) in requestjson.

Comment: `requestjson` has async code within it. You should expect the response in a callback. Before the outcome of the `requestjson` function you are triggering the `res.render` method

Comment: Thanks for that, and leading me down the right path. I've now got a second callback in the requestjson function and everything happens in the correct order. For the second callback, I've included an anon function and included the res.render method in- however, the res.render method doesn't call properly. I get "Cannot read property 'render' of undefined. I imagine I need to pass a parameter into it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem, I changed my requestjson call to

```
requestjson(randomizer.fetch, routerObj.jsonurl, function() {

res.render method....

}
```

and added an extra callback2(res) in requestjson.